# Can I use external SFF-8088 connector as a inexpensive way to get 2 more internal SFF-8087 ports?

Tags: raid

Here's the scenario:

I'm shopping between the LSI MegaRAID 9280-16 and 9280-24.  Both cards have a single external 8088 connector, but the difference is whether they have 6 or 4 8087 internal connectors.  Can I convert the external connector on the 9280-16 to 2 8087 ports to make a "ghetto" 9280-24?

What's also important is I want all of the drives connected to the card (either internally or externally) to be individually visible to the controller for Raid 50.  It would be bad if externally connected drives are only visible to the controller as a JBOD array. In other words, if I convert the 8088 connector to 2x8087, will the controller treat those two 8087 ports any different as the true internal 8087 ports?

Basically what I'm hoping to do is be able to buy the 9280-16, save $300 over the 9280-24, and still be able to plug in 24 SATA drives in RAID50.